# Can a file be stored as publicly available but automatically deleted upon app uninstallation?

Tags: android

Android provides a directory for app-private files that are automatically deleted when the app is uninstalled: `context.getExternalFilesDir()`. ([Documentaion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles))

And if you want files to be publicly available to all other apps, then you just put them somewhere relative to the root external directory, by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, and specifically if you want the file to be sorted into a media directory, you use `context.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles))

Is there a way to store a file that can be publicly accessed by other apps, but is automatically deleted when the app is uninstalled? And if so, what is the procedure? Is there any directory that can be assumed to be for temporary files?

I am looking for good practice for sharing an image to the Twitter app for attaching to a Tweet. It works fine using Fabric's TweetComposer if the file is in the public space from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but then there is the possibility that the file will not be cleaned up if my application is uninstalled before it gets to it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help or not but did you take a look at [`getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir())? The tricky part is that it satisfies one of your requirement.

> These files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled

But am not sure about the other one.

> These files are internal to the application, and not typically visible
>   to the user as media.

Not really sure as to what `typically` means and I couldn't find any other sources on the same. I guess it has to do with multiple users running on the same device as mentioned. If that is the case then most probably it shouldn't be a problem for you.

> Applications only have access to the external storage for the user
>   they're running as.

Comment: Sounds promising, since the documentation states, "There is no security enforced with these files."

And although it says it only cleans up the files at uninstallation in API 17 and later, since it's a cache directory, I would assume it will eventually get cleaned up anyway in lower versions. I'll give this a try with a Twitter attachment tonight or tomorrow and report back.